# How to store sql column name in form value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I'm new to php and MySQL (working through "Head First: PHP & MySQL").  I'm trying to grab a MySQL table column name from an array and store it in the "value" for an input field of a form. For some reason, I only end up with a blank page. When I simply type in some text into the 'value', the page turns out fine.

I've checked every line of code and have narrowed it down to the input value. The database connection works and I can echo the column name in the 'while' loop, but not in the 'value'.

Here's the code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> ">
    <?php 
        $dbc= mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'elvis_store')
            or die ('Error connecting to the database');

        $query= "SELECT * FROM elvis_emails";
        $result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query) 
            or die ('Error querying database');

        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'$row['Id']'" name="todelete[]"    />';
            echo $row['Id'];
            echo ' ' . $row['first_name'];
            echo ' ' . $row['last_name'];   
            echo ' ' . $row['email'];
            echo '<br />';
        }

        mysqli_close($dbc);


    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" />
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: first off, turn on error reporting, don't try to guess whats wrong, with the white screen of death. if its a typo, you should fix the missing concatenation `value="'$row['Id']'"`

Comment: thank you! i've tried to enable error reporting, but no errors get reported. i'll do some more research to figure out how to enable error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of,

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'$row['Id']'" name="todelete[]"    />';
```

try like this

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row["Id"].'" name="todelete[]"    />';
```

Comment: Thank you!! this solved my problem. thank you for catching this!

Answer (score 0):

What is really breaking the code is the missing of **proper concatenation**.

It's good practice to avoid printing HTML elements with PHP *echo* statement. Rather, the best approach **in this case** would be:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

<input type="checkbox" value="<?=$row['Id']?>" name="todelete[]" />

<?php
 ...
}

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

If by anyways you do need to print a piece of code that is relying on HTML tags and PHP variables you can make use of [HEREDOC](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead of using *echo* to print multiple lines of code.

> Also, make sure that you are naming the keys to the *row* array the
>   same as your query return values.

Comment: Guilherme, thank you for this excellent tip. It felt a bit strange to print HTML elements with an echo statement; thank you for clarifying a better way to do this.